# Function outputting the input questions in reverse order and improving the algorithm to account for equal numbers

Tags: c++

When I run the program it asks for the number of accidents in central region first, then works backwards to north. It should ask north, south, east, west, central in that order yet it outputs central -> north. Also as a challenge that was given to me, improving the algorithm to account for same number of accidents in different regions. The assignment allows the user to assume there is a different number of accidents per location, and the challenge is to improve that. The function names and types were dictated by the assignment. It works just fine and will get full credit even working backwards but I want to know why it's doing it for my own knowledge.

For the reverse order output I tried changing the line:
void findLowest(int north, int south, int east, int west, int central) 
to:
void findLowest(int central, int west, int east, int south, int north),
thinking I could trick it into processing how I want the output but it still went central -> north. For the improved algorithm challenge I started hard coding an else if statement in the findLowest function, continuing the statements with a else if(north == south || north == east...) etc but the amount of lines it would take to calculate everything seems over kill and complicated. I thought then I would put the equal numbered regions into a different variable for each place that was equal but then how would I dictate what the cout statement would be? In Python I think I would have put anything that was equal into a list or tuple and then printed that out by index or something to that effect but I don't know if that's possible in c++, haven't been exposed to anything like that yet. I'm stumped!

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int getNumAccidents(string location) {
    int numAccidents;
    cout << "How many accidents were reported in the " << location << " region of the city: ";
    cin >> numAccidents;
    while (numAccidents < 0) {
        cout << "The number of reported accidents must be a positive number." << endl <<
            "How many accidents were reported in the " << location << " region of the city: ";
            cin >> numAccidents;
    }
    return numAccidents;
};

void findLowest(int north, int south, int east, int west, int central) {
    string location;
    int lowestNumber;
    if (north < south && north < east && north < west && north < central){
        location = "north";
        lowestNumber = north;
    }
    else if (south < north && south < east && south < west && south < central) {
        location = "south";
        lowestNumber = south;
    }
    else if (east < north && east < south && east < west && east < central) {
        location = "east";
        lowestNumber = east;
    }
    else if (west < north && west < south && west < east && west < central) {
        location = "west";
        lowestNumber = west;
    }
    else if (central < north && central < south && central < east && central < west) {
        location = "central";
        lowestNumber = central;
    }
    cout << "\nThe city's " << location << " region had the lowest number of reported " <<
        "accidents last year. \nThat region's reported number of accidents was " <<
        lowestNumber << "." << endl;
};



int main()
{
    findLowest(getNumAccidents("north"), 
               getNumAccidents("south"), 
               getNumAccidents("east"), 
               getNumAccidents("west"), 
               getNumAccidents("central"));

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping four separate variables, use an array and then use `<algorithm>` functions to find the minimum and maximum values. Or if you want to sort you can use the `sort` function.

```
char *LOCATIONS[] = { "north", "south", "east", "west", "central" };

constexpr size_t N = 5;

int main()
{
    int a = getNumAccidents(LOCATIONS[0]);
    int b = getNumAccidents(LOCATIONS[1]);
    int c = getNumAccidents(LOCATIONS[2]);
    int d = getNumAccidents(LOCATIONS[3]);
    int e = getNumAccidents(LOCATIONS[4]);

    std::array<int, N> accidents = { a, b, c, d, e };

    // min is the iterator to the first position in the array that is minimum
    auto min = std::min_element(accidents.begin(), accidents.end());
    std::cout << "The least no. of accidents was " << *min << " occuring in the ";

    // calculate the position of that minimum element
    size_t minPos = std::distance(std::begin(accidents), min);
    std::cout << LOCATIONS[minPos] << " region.\n";
}
```

If you want to display them in a certain order, use the [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function passing in a comparison function indicating the order of the sort (ascending, descending, etc.)

Also, this design could be improved to use a map to associate the name of the location with the number of incidents there.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense! We have not started working with arrays yet and the structure I used is the assignment requirement so I'll have to stick with what I've got but I do see how that would work. I've been reading a bunch of other semi-related questions on stack and some other sites and I can't for the life of me figure out why it's asking for the input in reverse still. This was still educational tho so thank you! We tackle arrays in 2 weeks.